Masters Thesis ideas
I will begin studying at Kings college studying advanced Cyber Security, I have a passion for cryptography I can particularly express what, I just have found this topic so interesting for many years now,
I have worked in research which was integrating the algorithms (PQ round 3) into OpenSSL and some other stacks. I really like some of the PQ algorithms but I am unsure of a path to take for a thesis idea.
Any suggestions or pointers or any papers anyone have found interesting can you link for some inspiration?

I'd advise to check with faculty members, they often advertise (on their group's websites, or in conversation) potential topics which would be a good fit for doing a MSc thesis within their respective research groups. While I'm not familiar with the UK system, I'd be surprised if they expect you to come up with an idea for a thesis fully on your own.
If at all, this question would probably be a better fit for meta.crypto rather than here.

From my experience if you want to come up with your own thesis topic you need about 6 months of research reviewing the current bibligoraphy state of a specific field and this is if your direction don't require any extra mathematical knowledge if you want to come up with your own thesis idea. A professor that is active in research typically already possess this context and can save you time but you will be a bit more constrained about what you can do that he will support you theoretically and practically. By professor I mean his whole research team.

Inspiration: Watch Peter Gregory's TED talk in Silicon Valley (the comedy), S1E1. You can easily achieve £100/hr contracting in the Midlands if you have the chutzpah to make up a CV and pull it off. More in London. Consider that the UK doesn't reward education.
